# unable ro tun qpidd as daemon on cenotos7

Tags: permissions, centos7

I want to run apache qpidd as daemon on centos7 on startup but it fails becouse it is unable to lock a file

if I run it with "service qpidd start" and then inspect the status with "service qpidd status" it returns:

```
    [root@localhost ~]# service qpidd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  qpidd.service
● qpidd.service - An AMQP message broker daemon.
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/qpidd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-07-14 00:06:11 PDT; 22s ago
     Docs: man:qpidd(1)
           http://qpid.apache.org/
  Process: 3005 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/qpidd --config /etc/qpid/qpidd.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3005 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started An AMQP message broker daemon..
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting An AMQP message broker daemon....
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost.localdomain qpidd[3006]: 2017-07-14 00:06:11 [Broker] notice Broker (pid=3006) start-up
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost.localdomain qpidd[3005]: 2017-07-14 00:06:11 [Broker] critical Unexpected error: Daemon startup failed: Cannot lock /data/qpid/persistent/lock: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost.localdomain qpidd[3005]: Daemon startup failed: Cannot lock /data/qpid/persistent/lock: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: qpidd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit qpidd.service entered failed state.
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: qpidd.service failed.
```

On machine startup it has the same problem

log from /var/log/messages

```
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost systemd: Started An AMQP message broker daemon..
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost systemd: Starting An AMQP message broker daemon....
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost qpidd[3006]: 2017-07-14 00:06:11 [Broker] notice Broker (pid=3006) start-up
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost qpidd[3006]: 2017-07-14 00:06:11 [Broker] notice Broker (pid=3006) shut-down
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost qpidd[3005]: 2017-07-14 00:06:11 [Broker] critical Unexpected error: Daemon startup failed: Cannot lock /data/qpid/persistent/lock: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost qpidd: Daemon startup failed: Cannot lock /data/qpid/persistent/lock: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost systemd: qpidd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost systemd: Unit qpidd.service entered failed state.
Jul 14 00:06:11 localhost systemd: qpidd.service failed.
```

the permissions on the folder are as follows, I have also tried to set the permission to qpidd user but the same problem hapens:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cd /data/qpid/persistent/
[root@localhost persistent]# ll
total 4
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root  root  0 Jul 11 02:15 lock
drwxr-x---. 2 qpidd root 17 Jul 10 00:27 pq
drwxr-x---. 5 root  root 40 Jul 10 23:48 qls
-rw-r-----. 1 root  root 37 Jul 10 00:27 systemId
```

Comment: Try to set owner for lock to `qpidd` user.

Comment: have already tried does not work, the same problem persists